# Which validity to apply for when getting a Chinese visa?

Tags: visas, china

I would like to apply for a Chinese tourist visa and in my country, the cost for single, double and multiple entry visas is the same, regardless of duration.

I just have one round trip to China planned at the moment. As the cost is the same, could I apply for an "unnecessary generous" visa, i. e. something like a 2-year multiple entry visa, to get the most value out of the visa fee? Could it lead to my application being refused if the officer sees that I currently only need a 1-month single entry visa, or would my application simply be "downgraded"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you can ask for whatever kind of Chinese visa you like, and the consulate will ignore that give you what they think you need.

China does not normally issue multiple entry visas for first-time visitors. So whatever you apply for, they will probably give you a single entry tourist visa. If you want to visit again in the future, then they might decide to give you a multiple entry visa.

Comment: Ok, so it wouldn't hurt to apply for multiple entry, I might just not get it? That's good to know.

Comment: This is exactly true, you can ask for whatever you want and they will totally ignore you are issue what they feel like on the day. Unless you can prove that you already have tickets and hotels booked with official reservations